# How do I use Regenerator properly?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I'm playing Pokemon Black and I have a Mienfoo with the ability Regenerator on my team.

As Bulbapedia states [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Regenerator_(Ability))

> Regenerator restores ⅓ of the Pokémon's maximum HP upon switching out.

However, I'm not really sure how this ability can help me in the game. Does anyone have any advice on how to use Regenerator properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some advantages using **Regenerator** with your Mienfoo:

- It makes using recoil moves like *High Jump Kick* less risky (if it misses or fails, user loses half its max HP)
- It helps with *Life Orb* recoil (boosts power by 30% but makes the holder take 10% recoil each attack)
- It works amazingly well with *U-turn* (user attack then automatically switches).

More info on [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/pokemon/mienshao/).